# get another collection values using mongoDB and PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I have one collection like

```
"_id": ObjectId("58e33b757100a1e4543f9c5c"),
 "job_title": "Internship Job",
  "category_list": [
             "58de55747100a126748b4567",
              "570660fca88ae1415a3c9869",
              "5706645ea88ae1117a3c9869"
          ]
```

in the above collection category ids are from another collection of ObjectIds
Now i want to map this ids to category collection ids
simply i want category name instead of category ids by using PHP please can one help me out

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: So what is the issue ?

Comment: currently am fetching the data by looping ...if i have 2k documents its looping 2k times ..is there any solution get the data in one query

Comment: You could use [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup) with the aggregation framework.

Answer (score 0):

Several things you can try:

1. [DBRef](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/). You can think it as a shortcut of doing your loop. Only difference is it's done by MongoDB. So it's going to be slow, but convenient.
2. You can also try [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/). However it doesn't work for sharded cluster for now.

Data model design in MongoDB is mostly a matter of "balance". You can forget about normalization, just do whatever fits your use case best. In your case, consider embedding category name into your collection would probably make more sense since category name usually doesn't change very frequently. Thus you would mostly benefit from embedding. Rarely suffer from it. Once you do, the worst case is to update all category names.
The above assumption is based on the fact that "category name doesn't change frequently". It might not be real. So analyse base on your fact, how you do CRUD to the data? How frequently do you do them? Then try to find the model works best for your use case.

A good start would be reading the documentation [data model design](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/).